# IF NOT EXISTS in save function causing error

Tags: php, sql

In order to not save a user that already exists in the stage, I am using the following IF NOT EXISTS statement in my query.

```
public function save() {
    // new record
    if ( $this->id == null ) {
        $query = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE user_id ='{$this->user_id}' and stage_id = '{$this->stage_id}') INSERT INTO Table_A(".
            'id, '.
            'user_id, '.
            'stage_id, '.
            'create_date '.
            ') OUTPUT inserted.id '.
            'VALUES ('.
                'newid(), '. 
                '%s, '.
                '%s, '.  
                'getdate()'.
        ')';

$rs = $this->db->Execute($query);

        if ( $rs->EOF ) {
            return false;
        }

        $rs->Close();
}
```

**..It does the job, but when the user does exist it's throwing this error:**

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** ADODB.Recordset
**Description:** Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.'

Wasn't sure the best way to handle this was, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you close the Recordset by `$rs->Close();`, the next data fetch from the Recordset is not allowed. You could `return $rs;`, and after you get your data then close it.